# Fastest way to find switching from positive to negative in a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector that contains both positive and negative values. For example something like

`x = c(1,2,1,-2,-3,3,-4,5,1,1,-3)`

And now I want to flag the indices of the vector where the value changes from positive to negative or negative to positive.  So in the example above I would want something a vector of indices that looks something like this

`y=c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1)`

I am doing this in `R` so if possible I would like to avoid using for-loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
+(c(0, diff(sign(x))) != 0)
#[1] 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1

all.equal(+(c(0, diff(sign(x))) != 0), y)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: The same, slightly shorter: `c(0,!!diff(sign(x)))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
yy = rep(0, length(x))
yy[with(rle(sign(x)),{ p = cumsum(c(1,lengths)); p[ -c(1,length(p)) ] })] = 1

all.equal(yy,y) # TRUE
```

...which turned out more convoluted than I expected at first.